# How to Parse JSONarray inside JSONarray in android?

Tags: android, json, url

Hi every one I followed [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parsing-yql-using-json-tutorial/) one
to parse JSON from a URL but at the time of parsing I strucked at one place..
as

Now I am not getting images please Help. IMAGES, DETAILS ,OFFERS those are not Getting ..
They are in jsonarray(jsonobject(jsonarray(jsonobject))) please help

I have a image inside a array like below

```
{
"returnCode": "success",
"Data": {
    "results": [
        {
            "moredetails": [
                {
                    "newoffers": [
                        
                    ],
                    "recentoffers_count": 0,
                    "sku": "30072246"
                },
                {
                    "newoffers": [
                        {
                            "availability": "Available",
                            "currency": "USD"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "newoffers": [
                        {
                            "availability": "Available",
                            "currency": "USD"
                        }
                    ],
                    "offers_count": 1,
                    "name": "google.com"
                }
            ],
            ..."features": {
                ..
            },
            "length": "20",
            "geo": [
                "usa"
            ],
            .."images": [
                "http://google.com.one.jpg"
            ],
            ..
        }
    ],
    ...
   }
   }
```

Now I want how to parse some of the contents like Images, newoffers which are inside jsonarray(jsonarray) i mean they are like [{ [{ and [{[ json array inside  json array I tried but I am getting error at

```
JSONArray json_results = json_results.getJSONArray("images");
```

This is my code..

```
try {
JSONObject json_data = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(url);
JSONObject json_SemanticS3ProductData = json_data.getJSONObject("Data");
JSONArray json_results = json_SemanticS3ProductData.getJSONArray("results");
    for (int i = 0; i < json_SemanticS3ProductData.length(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    JSONObject c = json_results.getJSONObject(i);
    map.put("model", c.optString("model"));
    
    JSONObject f = c.getJSONObject("features");
    map.put("Rear-facing Camera", f.optString("Rear-facing Camera"));
    
        JSONArray json_results_images = json_results.getJSONArray("images");            
        arraylist.add(map);
        
            JSONArray json_sitedetails =json_results.getJSONArray("details");
            for (int j = 0; j < json_sitedetails.length(); j++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject sd = json_sitedetails.getJSONObject(j);
            JSONArray json_latestoffers = json_sitedetails.getJSONArray("offers");
            for (int k = 0; k < json_sitedetails.length(); k++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject e = json_latestoffers.getJSONObject(k);
            map1.put("currency", e.optString("currency"));                    
            arraylist.add(map1);
            }     
    }
  }
}
```

remaning all are fine. but I am unable to parse images,details,and offers.. please help.
Those three are inside the jsonarray(jsonObject (Jsonarray(jsonobject))) this is the thing..
Please help..

Comment: have a look at gson and the examples, it will easy up this.

Comment: plese give me answer regarding the above example I mean from this url (http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parsing-yql-using-json-tutorial/) not GSON.. I will try next one with GSON please tell me how to solve images...

Comment: have a look at this tut http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: @user3073115 Are you using the same link of that tutorial which you have defined ?

Comment: Can you use a valid json example?

Comment: are you able to retrieve image string from jsonarray ?

Comment: Yes sir I am able to get images hence its a url but the problem is that it is in  jsonarray(jsonObject (Jsonarray(jsonobject))) so I am unable to parse details,offers and images.. please help..

Comment: i have some other data which is form url  i am not using its just parsing error, and i have a valid json data also refered in jsonlint.com... please give me solution of this kind not GSON.. because i almost done 99%,..

Comment: post your total json output so that i'll check

Comment: harish sir i got answer for images only two things needed details and offers

Answer (score 0):

I created an incomplete snippet. With your given example it can access at least up to the first new_offers, sku, etc. This is incomplete though as it will fail if a field does not exist. Anyway the purpose of the snippet is just to show you how to retrieve the value from a nested JSONObject and JSONArray

```
    JSONObject root = new JSONObject(sample);
    String returnCode = root.getString("returnCode");
    Log.d(TAG, "returnCode:" + returnCode);

    JSONObject data = root.getJSONObject("Data");
    JSONArray results = data.getJSONArray("results");
    int resultsSize = results.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < resultsSize; i++) {
        JSONObject result = results.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray moreDetails = result.getJSONArray("moredetails");
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < moreDetails.length(); i2++) {
            JSONObject detail = moreDetails.getJSONObject(i2);
            JSONArray newOffers = detail.getJSONArray("newoffers");

            int recentOffersCount = detail.getInt("recentoffers_count");
            String sku = detail.getString("sku");

            Log.d(TAG, "recentOffersCount:"+recentOffersCount);
            Log.d(TAG, "sku:"+sku);

            // Will fail on the 2nd moreDetail because the field is incomplete. be sure to handle it.
        }
        JSONObject features = result.getJSONObject("features");
        int length = result.getInt("length");
        JSONArray geo = result.getJSONArray("geo");
        JSONArray images = result.getJSONArray("images");
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < images.length();i2++) {
            String image = images.getString(i2);
            Log.d(TAG, "image:"+image);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `JSONArray json_results_images = json_results.getJSONArray("images");` should be `JSONArray json_results_images = c.getJSONArray("images");`

Comment: fine sir and what about details and offers sir.. please hlep.. only two things