# How to parse Json data from URL?which contains number of arrays

Tags: android, json, parsing

i am having a issue of parsing JSON data i followed [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parsing-yql-using-json-tutorial/) link..

over there it has parsing data images description..

and i also refereed this in stack over flow a guy who is having same issue but no correct  answer..
[How to Parse JSONarray inside JSONarray in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699627/how-to-parse-jsonarray-inside-jsonarray-in-android) and
[How to display Image from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716333/how-to-display-image-from-url/20716395?noredirect=1#comment31033707_20716395)

we can say just extention of the above questions..

its not a duplicate that guy is also same problem no answer..

i have a data like below

```
{
"request": "ok",
"query": {
    "result": [
        {
            "site": [
                {
                    "latest": [
                        {
                            "id": "2eaQy8Ow",
                            "data": "1/1/2014"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "flag": [
                "http://www.simplydecoded.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Telangana2.jpg"
            ]
        }
    ]
   }
  }
```

i am using below code for parsing

```
JSONArray json_query_flag = c.getJSONArray("flag");


JSONArray json_query_site=c.getJSONArray("site");
System.out.println("looping json_query_site");
for (int j = 0; j < c.length(); j++) {
System.out.println("looping json_query_site[" + j +"]" + "json_query_site.length() -->" + json_query_site.length());

if (j <json_query_site.length()) {

HashMap<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
JSONObject sd = json_query_site.getJSONObject(j);

// get latestoffers
JSONArray json_latest = sd.getJSONArray("latest");
System.out.println(json_latest.toString());

for (int k = 0; k < json_latest.length(); k++) {

HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
JSONObject e = json_latest.getJSONObject(k);
```

My problem is that i am not getting the latest and flag..
may be parsing problem..

Comment: Sir that is in c# i am in java android .. and my code is designed from this url http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parsing-yql-using-json-tutorial/

Comment: Sorry this is answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635220/json-parser-for-recursive-structure/20635380#20635380 is no way related to question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hellow man thanks for understanding the problem please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699627/how-to-parse-jsonarray-inside-jsonarray-in-android) post for the till your site and latest..

it solved I am getting text.. but problem with images I think you have flag.. 
for that you need to change your Listviewadapter.java file. so that images will appear

change this like

```
String strflag = resultp.get(Mainactivity.IMAGES);
    if(strflag != null)
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(strflag, flag);
    else
        imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://www.butterentals.com/graphics/no_image.jpg", flag);
```

so that I will be done.

Answer (score 1):

TRy this..

```
JSONObject JObj = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject query = JObj.getJSONObject("query");
JSONArray result = query.getJSONArray("result");
for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jobj = result.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray site = jobj.getJSONArray("site");
            for (int j = 0; j < site.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject sitobj = site.getJSONObject(j);
                JSONArray latest = sitobj.getJSONArray("latest");
                    for (int k = 0; k < latest.length(); k++) {
                         JSONObject lateobj = latest.getJSONObject(k);
                         System.out.println("id : "+lateobj.getString("id"));
                    }
            }
        JSONArray flag = jobj.getJSONArray("flag");
        for (int l = 0; l < flag.length(); l++) {
            System.out.println("urls : "+flag.getString(l));
        }
}
```

Comment: @user3124880 can you post your full parsing code that missing **C** `JSONObject`

Comment: @user3124880 yes i know that. for your json response my ans is correct. May i know what you want.

Comment: @user3124880 sorry friend i'm in office i cannot open my mail here. you can post your parsing code i can help you.

Comment: @user3124880 see my ans take that code and use it. check that in logcat that urls will print.

Comment: @user3124880 in hashmap1 which data you need to store.

Comment: Sorry sir remaning all data i am storing in hashmap but images data also am getting but not displaying please solve sir i think problem with image loader  here is the image loader sir.. please do me this favor sir... i cant post entire image loader code sir..