# how to parse and display a url contents inside a json array?

Tags: android, arrays, json

i have a images inside a jsonarray but like `"flag": [
                "http://www.simplydecoded.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Telangana2.jpg"
            ]`

but not displaying..

i am using [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parsing-yql-using-json-tutorial/) tutorial for parsing the data

and i sucessfully parsed all data but except images are not coming

i am using this to call images which are in side a json array actually its a url..

```
JSONArray json_query_flag = c.getJSONArray("flag");
```

and i followd remaning all fro [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716999/how-to-parse-json-data-from-urlwhich-contains-number-of-arrays) question..

it just extention of that not duplicate..

and i am using below for the part for the part of downloading image to bitmap

```
public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
        .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService;
// Handler to display images in UI thread
Handler handler = new Handler();

public ImageLoader(Context context) {
    fileCache = new FileCache(context);
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

final int stub_id = R.drawable.temp;

public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
    if (bitmap != null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if (b != null)
        return b;

    // Download Images from the Internet
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                .openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
            memoryCache.clear();
        return null;
    }
}

// Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
        stream1.close();

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        // Recommended Size 512
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 2;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 4;
            height_tmp /= 4;
            scale *= 4;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
        stream2.close();
        return bitmap;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

// Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad {
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;

    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
        url = u;
        imageView = i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            handler.post(bd);
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
    String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

// Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
        bitmap = b;
        photoToLoad = p;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if (bitmap != null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}

}
```

Comment: i didnt get you what you want.you want parse image url or you want image?

Comment: hello madam actually i am parsing json data but images are not displaying in the image view..

Comment: you have to load image from url.

Comment: yes medam but it is inside a json array and that is  inside a json array like jsonarray(jsonobject(jsonarray(jsonobject)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
JSONArray json_query_flag = c.getJSONArray("flag");
for(int i=0;i<json_query_flag.length();i++)
{
    Log.v("URL"+json_query_flag.getString(i));
}
```

**EDIT**

```
ImageLoader imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.this);
```

and set image as

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(URL, imageview);
```

here `imageview` is name of that imageview and URl is that string Url

OR

```
 Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        imageURL = new URL(utl2);
    }

    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageURL
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @user3124880 did you get the url or not.

Comment: @user3124880 did you give internet permission

Comment: yes sir the entire data is loading froma url but except image is not loading

Comment: this is also not working sir.. i think it should auto load from a array but its not loading if its like "flag":"http://www.simplydecoded.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Telangana2.jpg" we can easily but its inside a array.. thats problem